# SVG: how to use 100% width/height but with fixed scale

Tags: svg

I have an SVG that needs to be opened in a container of variable size but initially scaled down to exactly 4 times screen DPI (so that 1 pixel corresponds to 4 units of the SVG user space).

[Here's the example SVG](http://rustyx.org/temp/temp.svg). When it is opened, it must occupy the whole viewport, without scrollbars, but with a fixed scale of 1/4 (in relation to screen DPI).

The only way I can specify SVG scaling is by specifying `viewBox`.

The only way I can use the whole container is by specifying `width="100%" height="100%"`.

But when both of these are specified, the SVG is automatically scaled based on container size.

Is there no solution to this simple requirement, without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: I don't get it. The only ways you can specify SVG scaling is with the `transform="scale(x)"` attribute, or with a `<view>` element. viewBox is not really about the scale, but... about the viewBox (the viewable rect of your whole document that should be shown). Now, the only way I can think of to get the screen's dpi is via [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), where you'd have to set a different `transform:scale()` for each possible resolution ... or use js to get and set it (you can also append js in your svg file)